# Is there an easy way to migrate a site from SiteFinity to WordPress?

Tags: migration

Has anyone ever migrated a site from SiteFinity to WordPress?  I've got a large (1,200+ page) site that I'm transitioning over to WordPress and I'm not looking forward to the content migration.

Does anyone know of a tool, trick or plugin to make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that as of today, there is no easy automated way to do the migration.  Closing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Our [service](http://migratetowp.com/) offers this option (not for free though :-) )